# R caret not using all rows in training

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am trying to build a randomforest model using the caret package in R. The training data has 287 samples and 147 variables, testing partition is 119 x 147. Here is part of my code

```
##Split into training and validation samples
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=all_subj_summ$out, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
training <- all_subj_summ[inTrain,]
testing <- all_subj_summ[-inTrain,]

#fit a model using RandomForest using all variables
set.seed(123)
tc <- trainControl(method="cv")
mod <- train(out ~ ., method="rf", data=training, prox=TRUE, trControl=tc)
preds <- predict(mod,testing)
table(preds, testing$out)
confusionMatrix(testing$out, preds)
```

However when i try to print the table or confusion matrix, i get an error

```
> confusionMatrix(testing$out, preds)
Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

It turns out that the model when applied to the testing partition is only predicting 64 values and not all the 119 rows in the testing set. When i examine the rf model also i see that not all 287 samples (from the training set) are used. I understood that during bootstrapping, we use the same number of samples (with replacement) ... see output of the model below

```
> mod
Random Forest 

287 samples
146 predictors
  5 classes: 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'NaN' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 

Summary of sample sizes: 139, 137, 137, 138, 138, 138, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
    2   0.763     0.691  0.0917       0.123   
   74   0.763     0.693  0.0913       0.123   
  146   0.750     0.678  0.0910       0.122   

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 74.
```

Can someone shed light on why rf is using only 130-odd samples for building the model and secondly when applied to predict the outcome, why are only 64 examples predicted? Thanks!

Comment: I figured out that if we impute missing values before submitting to caret for cross validation, the model will predict all the 119 records in the  testing set (my second question above). However the model still only bootstraps less than the full number of records in the training.

Comment: Are you sure there are no problems with your data? There is a class "NaN". I am not able to reproduce this, because train(method = "rf") throws an error when trying to fit a model that has NaN in the response variable.